# ¿Cómo obtener valores (chequeado o no) de los Checkbox dentro de una tabla?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

Mi código es bastante sencillo. Tengo 4 casillas de verificación (checkbox) en una table de 2X2. 
Cuando quiero obtener el valor del checkbox de una celda específica (checkeado o no) obtengo UNDEFINED. 
Vean que específicamente busco el valor de la celda (0,0) en la matríz mediante esta instrucción que evidentemente no responde a lo que quiero: document.getElementById("myTable").rows[0].cells[0]

¿Que estoy haciendo mal? Gracias.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    table,
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <p>Tratando de obtener valores de los checkbox dentro de una tabla.</p>

  <table id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <td id='C1'> <input type='checkbox' checked='checked' </td>
        <td id='C2'> <input type='checkbox' checked='checked' </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id='C3'> <input type='checkbox' checked='checked' </td>
        <td id='C4'> <input type='checkbox' checked='checked' </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <p id="print1"></p>
  <p id="print2"></p>
  <p id="print3"></p>
  <p id="print4"></p>

  <br>

  <button onclick="myFunction()">Intentarlo</button>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById("print1").innerHTML = document.getElementById("myTable").rows[0].cells[0].checked;

    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Tienes errores tanto en el HTML como en el JavaScript. A continuación
>   te dejo el código revisado. Espero que sea útil:

```js
let output = document.getElementById("print1");
//el array de las casillas de verificación
let checkboxes = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#myTable [type='checkbox']"));


let button = document.querySelector("button");

function myFunction() {
     let n = 0;  
     checkboxes.map((c) =>{
       if(c.checked){n++}
     });
     output.innerHTML = n;
    }

button.addEventListener("click", myFunction);
```

```html
 <p>Trying to obtain the values of the checkbox inside a table.</p>

  <table id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <td id='C1'> <input type='checkbox' /> </td>
        <td id='C2'> <input type='checkbox' /> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id='C3'> <input type='checkbox'  /></td>
        <td id='C4'> <input type='checkbox' /> </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <p id="print1"></p>
  <p id="print2"></p>
  <p id="print3"></p>
  <p id="print4"></p>

 

  <button>Try it</button>
```

ACTUALIZACIÓN: *He añadido otro bloque de código explicando como encontrar la posición de una casilla de verificación marcada (checked) en el array de los checkboxes.*

Espero haber entendido bien tu pregunta. En el siguiente bloque de código hay algunos cambios.

De entrada hay 15 casillas de verificación (checkbox) en 3 filas y 5 columnas).

En el JavaScript hay 2 variables más: `let rows = 3;` y `let columns = 5;` Si sacas en consola `console.log(checkboxes.length)` te da 15.

En la función `myFunction()` utilizo el método `map()` para iterar el array de las casillas de verificación `checkboxes`.

Esta vez `map` toma 2 argumentos:

`c` - el checkbox y

`i` el index del checkbox, o sea su posición en el array `checkboxes`.

Para saber la fila donde se encuentra: `console.log(~~(i/columns))`

Para saber en que columna: `console.log(i%columns)`

¡OJO! todo empieza desde 0, así que la primera columna es la columna 0, y la 3-a columna es la columna 2.

```js
let output = document.getElementById("print1");
let checkboxes = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#myTable [type='checkbox']"));
let rows = 3;
let columns = 5;

let button = document.querySelector("button");
function myFunction() {
     let n = 0;  
     checkboxes.map((c,i) =>{
       
       if(c.checked){n++;
          console.log("el index del checkbox en el array checkboxes:",i)
          console.log("el número de la fila:",~~(i/columns));
          console.log("el número de la columna:",i%columns);
       }
     });
     output.innerHTML = n;
    }

button.addEventListener("click", myFunction);
```

```html
  <table id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <td> <input type='checkbox' /> </td>
      <td> <input type='checkbox' /> </td>
      <td> <input type='checkbox' /></td>
      <td> <input type='checkbox' /></td>
      <td> <input type='checkbox' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> <input type='checkbox' /></td>
      <td> <input type='checkbox' /> </td>
      <td> <input type='checkbox' /> </td>
      <td> <input type='checkbox' /></td>
      <td> <input type='checkbox' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> <input type='checkbox' /></td>
      <td> <input type='checkbox' /></td>
      <td> <input type='checkbox' /></td>
      <td> <input type='checkbox' /></td>
      <td> <input type='checkbox' /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <p id="print1"></p>


 

  <button>Try it</button>
```

Comment: se agradece tu ayuda, pero el sitio es en español y no se deben por tanto responder preguntas en inglés, -1

Comment: Gracias Alfredo Paz por tu comentario. Previamente he editado el texto de su pregunta, que he traducido al castellano; pero parece que será visible solo para mi hasta que lo revisen los pares. ¿No es esto lo que se supone que hay que hacer?

Comment: tu no debes traducir la pregunta, debe ser el mismo OP quien lo haga

Comment: Estimados, no hay problema, estoy tratando de re editarlo en español pero no me resulta amigable. Gracias enxaneta!! lo veo y te comento. Es bastante distinto el código!

Comment: ENXANETA: Cómo obtengo el valor del checkbox dentro de la celda? mediante esta instrucción DOM: document.getElementById("myTable").rows[0].cells[0] ??? Quiero obtener true/false, 0/1 o lo que sea. Gracias!!

Comment: Dlorko if(c.checked) devuelve true o false. Puedes escribir `console.log(checkboxes[0].checked)` para saber si la primera casilla de verificación está marcada o no